# ASP.NET MVC Submit button localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, form-submit

I have localizaed ASP.NET MVC application with view:

```
 <button type="submit" value="@Resources.Yes">
 <button type="submit" value="@Resources.No">
```

and cotroller:

```
public ActionResult Index(..., string submit)
{           
   switch (submit)
   {
      case "Yes":    
      default:
           .....
           break;
      case "No":
           ....
           break;
    }
}
```

But it works obviously only for English. How do you solve the submit button detection for multiple languages?

I have found article http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx, where they use attributs, but I can't use it, because localization is not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view model, include a string property for each button:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string YesButton { get; set; }
    public string NoButton { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
<input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.YesButton)" value="@Resources.Yes" />
<input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.NoButton)"  value="@Resources.No" />
```

In the controller, only the property associated with the button that the user clicked on will contain a value.  The other "button" properties will be null.  So:

```
// Do something if the user clicked on the Yes button
if (model.YesButton!= null) <Do Something>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I don't like it too much, but if you have better solution, please post it:

View:

```
 <button type="submit" value="@Resources.Yes">
 <button type="submit" value="@Resources.No">
```

and cotroller:

```
private enum IndexSubmitResult{Yes, No};

private IndexSubmitResult? GetSubmitButton(string submit)
{
   if(submit == MyProject.Resources.Views.Home.Index.Yes)
      return IndexSubmitResult.Yes;
   else if(submit == MyProject.Resources.Views.Home.Index.No)
      return IndexSubmitResult.No;
   else
      return null;
}

public ActionResult Index(..., string submit)
{           
   switch (GetSubmitButton(submit))
   {
      case IndexSubmitResult.Yes:    
      default:
           .....
           break;
      case IndexSubmitResult.No:
           ....
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a resource file in your assembly or in another assembly.
Make a viewmodel class with a string property.
Use the Display Attribute like this.

```
public class ViewModelClass
{
    [Display(Name = "locproperty ", ResourceType = typeof(YourResoureFile))]
    public string locproperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view use it like this

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="~/Controller/Action" @Html.LabelFor(m => m.locproperty ) </a>
```